# Android Shuffle String Array, then split shuffled array into individual TextViews

Tags: android, arrays

I've got a simple 3 item array that I've shuffled and output into a single texview. What I'd like to do is output each number into it's own textview. I've got this code, but at `chop[0];` and `chop[2];` I'm getting the error `Syntax error on token ";", invalid AssignmentOperator`. Maybe I'm doing the chopping of the array totally wrong? Here's the code:

```
        String[] numbArray = { "1", "2", "3" };
    List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s: numbArray)
        aList.add(s);
    Collections.shuffle(aList);
    for (String showNum : aList) {
        String[] chop = showNum.split(" ");
        chop[0];
        chop[1];
        chop[2];

        textview1.setText(chop[0]);
        textview2.setText(chop[1]);
        textview3.setText(chop[2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
String[] numbArray = { "1", "2", "3" };
List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s: numbArray)
    aList.add(s);
Collections.shuffle(aList);
TextView[] textViews = {textview1, textview2, textview3};
for (int i = 0; i<textViews.lenght; i++) {
    textviews[i].setText(aList.get(i));
}
```

The lines:

```
chop[0];
chop[1];
chop[2];
```

are incorrect because they do nothing. The compiler expect that you assign some value to those references.

Comment: you thought right Brais Gabin, your solution works! thank you. And I see now what you mean about the chop[0]; ... being pointless.